# Lucene search returning same value two times

Tags: solr, lucene, lucene.net

[image]Below is my json response from solr index,

```
> <doc> <str name="longitudeCoordinate">11.2409</str> <str
> name="chainName">Pegasus Connect</str> <str
> name="currencyCode">EUR</str> <str name="entityType">hotelInfo</str>
> <str name="propertyName">BELLA VISTA</str> <str
> name="chainCode">UZ</str> <str name="marketerName">Pegasus
> Solutions</str> <str name="disableReasonId">A</str> <str
> name="propertyId">100003</str> <str name="marketerId">PEGASUS</str>
> <str name="propertyStatus">Inactive</str> <str
> name="latitudeCoordinate">43.77691</str> <str
> name="countryCode">ES</str> </doc>
```

To retrive this details i written the below lucene search i framed the below query,

```
+entityType:hotelInfo +(propertyId:100003) +(marketerId:PEGASUS) +(chainCode:UZ) +(+propertyName:bella +propertyName:vista*) +(disableReasonId:P disableReasonId:C disableReasonId:A)
```

But it's giving same results two times.

```
if (hotelName != null) {
                StandardAnalyzer analyzer;
                analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer(Version.LUCENE_46);
                QueryParser queryParser = new QueryParser (Version.LUCENE_46, "propertyName", analyzer);
              //  queryParser.setAllowLeadingWildcard (true);
                queryParser.setDefaultOperator(QueryParser.Operator.AND);
                Query pNameQuery = null;
                try {
                    pNameQuery = queryParser.parse (hotelName + "*");

                } catch (ParseException e) {

                    e.printStackTrace ();
                } finally {
                    analyzer.close ();
                }
                hotelInfoQuery.add (pNameQuery, BooleanClause.Occur.MUST);
            }
```

I added only the part responsible for filtering the property-name.It will be useful if i get which part of code is creating multiple results and help to rectify it.

Regards,
Raghavan